# How to upload canvas and image to the server with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I have html code as follows:

```
<div id="wrapper">
     <img id="photo" src="http://autralis.blob.core.windows.net/thumbnails/1024x768/36/74/57/36745738883478623422431720268247042049573454290037543508541937745291910806066.jpg"/>
     <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
<button id="save-button" onclick="onSaveChanges()">Save</button>
```

Thus I have an image and on that image I want to draw canvas. That works fine.

But now I want to upload it to the server, but not only the canvas. I want to upload image and the canvas, together as one image. How can I do that?

Here is my js code where I try to upload it:

```
function onSaveChanges(){
    save_button_label.classList.add('hide');
    save_button_spinner.classList.remove('hide');

    var body = new FormData();
    var canvasData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    body.append('photo', canvasData);


    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', url);

    xhr.onload = function (e) {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            // const result = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            renderMessage(success, upload_success_msg)
        }
    };
    xhr.onerror = function (e) {
        renderMessage(errors, upload_error_msg)
    };
    xhr.send(body);
}
```

But with `var canvasData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");` I get only the canvas, and not the image also.

Any idea what can I do to upload image and canvas together as one image?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

[image]

The red border is canvas and the blue border is the image. I want to upload it as one image, thus both together as one.

Comment: try this - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob - then you can easily add the Blob to the FormData and transfer it to the server, you can add any image to the FormData, even the one inside the img tag

Comment: @Roomy I do not know if I understand it good. But with `var canvasData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");` I get the canvas data as base64, and that is fine. I want to use `<img id="photo" src="url.jpg"/>` and combine it with canvas to create one image and then upload it to the server.

Comment: how do you want to combine them? to make the img as a background of the canvas? or just to send them together in one request to the server?

Comment: @Roomy See updated question. I want to send them in one request but as one image. That means probably `to make the img as a background of the canvas`.

Comment: ok, I see so maybe add the source of the `img` as a background of the canvas?

Comment: @Roomy If I do it so, I get something as `<img src="blob:http://localhost:63342/cace32eb-dd3d-4fb6-b809-33ada709f80d" style="background-image: url("http://autralis.blob.core.windows.net/thumbnails/1024x768/36/74/57/36745738883478623422431720268247042049573454290037543508541937745291910806066.jpg");">`. If I try to save it as image, I get `Failed. No image`

Answer (score 0):

I changed html a little bit:

```
<div id="result" style="background-color: red;">
     <img id="photo" src="assets/images/audi.png"/>
     <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

And I used [HTML2Canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) library, which takes a screenshot of the whatever you want and save it as image.

The javascript is as follows:

```
function upload_to_server(canvasData){

    return fetch(api_url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify({photo: canvasData})
    }).then(function (value) {
        if(value.ok){
            return value.json().then(function (response) {
                // Do something with response
            })
        }
    }).catch(function (reason) {
        // Handle error
    })

}

function onSaveChanges(){
    save_button_label.classList.add('hide');
    save_button_spinner.classList.remove('hide');

    html2canvas(document.getElementById("result")).then(function(canvas) {
        var canvasData = canvas.toDataURL("image/" + image_type + "");
        upload_to_server(canvasData)
    });
}
```

I hope that it will help someone.